# formula for discount

Tags: php, math, formula

What is the formula for discount,

in php is there any default function ,

this is my formula, chk it is correct way ,

```
  $SELLING_PRICE = $ACTUAL_PRICE-$CHK_DISCOUNT_THERE;
  $PRICE_AFTER_DISCOUNT = $ACTUAL_PRICE-$SELLING_PRICE;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
selling price = actual price - (actual price * (discount / 100))
```

So for example if (actual price) = $15, (discount) = 5%

```
selling price = 15 - (15 * (5 / 100)) = $14.25
```

Comment: i think formula should be $PRICE_AFTER_DISCOUNT = $ACTUAL_PRICE - ($ACTUAL_PRICE * ($CHK_DISCOUNT_THERE / 100));

Comment: selling price = 15 - (15 * (5 / 100)) = $14.25

Answer (score 2):

Like Literally you can copy paste this formula:

```
$total = $total - ($total * ($discount_amount/100));
```